# store dynamic table content in database

Tags: excel, oracle, dynamic

Hello I need some help here.

I have to design a database table for an oracle db that can store excel file content.

The problem is that i have to expect a variaty of formats. That means i
dont know how many columns are in the excel file or how long the content 
of each column might be.

But I need a table that i can refer to get the content of the file after it was imported.

Usually you know what kind of data you get but in this case i dont know that.

Is there a way to store informations like this in an relational database ?
And no i can't just put the file in a blob column i need the cells separated.

Comment: Sometimes things are not within your control, but if you push hard enough to demand that a particular format, or group of formats, be adhered to then it will make everyone's lives a little easier. If you have a set of known incoming formats, you can do a data transform on those and store everything in one table; otherwise create a the several table formats you need and import directly to them.

Comment: ok i guess i will provide some sort of profiling mechanism to specify the column types and store the data in a table with a predefined set of columns.